# django registration module with multiple registration forms

Tags: django-registration

I want to use 2 different forms for registering Seller and buyer using dhango registration module. Both forms will be different. I have created accounts/forms for both forms, but not sure how to invoke the different template for different user categories. In both the cases, it is invoking default `registration_form.html`.

here is my `accounts/forms.py`

```
class UserRegForm(RegistrationForm):
    news_letter=forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
    first_name=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name=forms.CharField(max_length=30)


class SellerRegForm(RegistrationFormTermsOfService):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
    shop_name=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    mobile_number=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    address=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    city=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    state=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    pin_code=forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Comment: The templates are usually selected in the views or possibly the urls. You might want to post the relevant information from these as well.

Comment: yes I need to post different data from different forms